# Launching an UI or an application when a system tray notification is clicked

Tags: c++, notifications, system-tray

I have created a system tray icon notification. I need to launch an application when the notification is clicked. How can I do that using C++? I have read about the `IUserNotification2` interface from MSDN documents, but I'm not sure how to implement them. It would be so helpful if someone can share an example code for a click event.

Comment: How are you creating the tray icon in the first place? Are you using `Shell_NotifyIcon()`, `IUserNotification2`, or something else? Please show your actual code. Either way should be sending you a notification message/event when the icon is clicked on. You can do whatever you want when t that happens. Display a UI window, start a new process, etc.

Comment: I am using IUserNotification2->show  to create the trayicon and when it is clicked it calls a function OnBaloonUserclick,The IUserNotificationCallBack variable returns a result .but i don't know how to access it.

Comment: you are supposed to write a new class that derives from `IUserNotificationCallback` and overrides its methods. Then you create an instance of that class and pass it to `Show()`, and your overridden methods will be called when the corresponding actions are performed by the user